# File exists but PHP throwing "failed to open stream: no such file or directory"

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to pull a random string from a .txt file on my server in order to display it in the footer of my site. Here is the code I am using (the first two lines are purely for debugging purposes):

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="instructions">
        <?php
            $file = include_once 'facts.txt';
            echo dirname(__FILE__);
            $f_contents = file('facts.txt');
            $line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
            echo $line;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is what gets displayed in my footer:

```
TEST LINE - FOR TESTING PURPOSES.

/HOME/LEWIHTYV/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-CONTENT/THEMES/LEWNACY

WARNING: FILE(FACTS.TXT) [FUNCTION.FILE]: FAILED TO OPEN STREAM: NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY IN /HOME/LEWIHTYV/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-CONTENT/THEMES/LEWNACY/FOOTER.PHP ON LINE 6

WARNING: ARRAY_RAND() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE ARRAY, BOOLEAN GIVEN IN /HOME/LEWIHTYV/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-CONTENT/THEMES/LEWNACY/FOOTER.PHP ON LINE 7
```

For some reason, even through the file is being recognised when being included and the directory is correct (the footer.php and facts.txt files are both in the same directory), the random line selection is throwing this error. I have tested this code locally using WAMP and I have had no problems whatsoever. I have also checked the file permissions to make sure it is readable.

Comment: What is the output of: `echo $file;` ?

Comment: You don't want to use `include once` here.  Also  if you are getting the directory save it in a variable. THen prepend the variable in the `file($dir . 'facts.txt');`

Comment: Why is your error all in caps? Anyways, it sounds like you are working with Linux (based on path in error) and Windows (WAMP). This can cause several wierd problems, but I would guess yours stems from: Windows is not case-sensitive, Linux is case-sensitive. Check that.

Comment: Also `include_once` will not error if the file is not found. Thats what `require_once` is for.

Comment: I should clarify I am using Windows - the error is only in all caps as I copied it straight from the rendered page (CSS text-transform: uppercase on that particular element).

Comment: @Rizier123 `echo $file;` returns `1`

Comment: @lewisj Then whats up with the file path? That doesn't look like a Windows path?

Comment: @dan08 Sorry, I misinterpreted what you were saying - the server is indeed Linux.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is PHP doesn't automatically assume that "facts.txt" is in the same directory as the PHP file that's running. You have to tell it the full path.

Try:

```
$f_contents = file(dirname(__FILE__) . '/facts.txt');
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked! I'm fairly new to PHP so I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: If you have PHP >= 5.3, then you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507